# Javascript say Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this function:

```
$( "#contact" ).on( "click", function() {
  var email = $(this).attr(email);
  var sendGmail = function(){
    var str = 'http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1'+
        '&to=' + to +
        '&su=' + subject +
        '&body=' + message.replace(/\n/g,'%0A') +
        '&ui=1';
    location.href = str;
  };
  sendGmail({
    to: email,
    subject: 'Obavestenje u vezi aukcije ',
    message: 'Postovani, \n'+
    ' \n'+
    'Cestitamo, \n'+
    'Obavestavamo Vas da je Vasa ponuda pobedila na aukciji \n'+
    ' \n'+
    'Uskoro Vas kontaktiramo telefonon \n'+
    ' \n'+
    ' \n'+
    ' \n'+
    ' \n'+
    'Srdacan pozdrav i hvala na ukazanom poverenju. Radujemo se buducoj saradnji\n'
  });


});
```

of course I have html:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="contact" email="aaa.ddd@gmail.com">Contact user!</button>
```

But now when I click on btton I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

I really dont know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: There's no `nodeType` in your function.

Comment: Your giving the function an object with properties, but your function doesn't accept any parameters.  You could use the arguments variable but your not using that either...  Either change your method pass in each parameter, or add that one parameter and use it to access the properties off of it in the method.

Comment: ok, thanks, please write as answer to accept as right answer

Comment: This in not correct : $(this).attr(email), you need to do this instead: $(this).attr('email'). You want to get the email attribute but do way you do you are passing a variable in there. For the other parameter you are passing incorrectly  you already have a comment from Taplar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have an undefined variable here:

```
$(this).attr(email);
//-----------^
```

Guess you need to replace it using:

```
$(this).attr("email");
```